# Como faço para Comparar campos de tabelas diferentes usando HAVING

Tags: sql, firebird, group-by

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta SQL no Firebird onde só irá retornar dados caso a soma dos campos da primeira tabela for diferente do Campo `"vlrnota"` da segunda tabela. Porém ao tentar rodar o `SELECT`, acusa erro

> Invalid expression in the select list (not contained in either an aggregate function or the `GROUP BY` clause)

```
SELECT sum((vlrunit*qtdade)+VLRICMSUBSTITUICAO+d.vlripi+d.vlriss-valdesconto+valacrescimo)soma, 
d.numero, 
vlrnota 
FROM MOVIMENTACAO m

left join documentos d
on m.iddoc = d.iddoc

Group by vlrnota 
HAVING VLRNOTA = (SELECT sum((vlrunit*qtdade)+VLRICMSUBSTITUICAO+d.vlripi+d.vlriss-valdesconto+valacrescimo) AS SOMA FROM MOVIMENTACAO)
```

Comment: Lucas*, quando voce faz uma soma ou outra função que une informações, todos os campos que estão no SELECT sem ser uma SOMA ou um COUNT precisam estar dentro do GROUP BY, nesse caso voce precisa inserir o campo d.numero, pois a soma dele esta no Select dentro do HAVING, e no caso doseu "Main" Select ele n esta como SOMA e sim como um campo normal. Teste apenas colocar o d.numero no seu Group By. Se continuar não funcionando existem outros possiveis erros dentro do seu Select que posso ajudar.

Comment: Gigliotti, Fiz o que voce falou, porém agora deu outro erro: "Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Invalid expression in the HAVING clause (neither an aggregate function nor a part of the GROUP BY clause)"

Comment: Nesse caso como comentei que poderia haver outro erro que eu acredito que seja no seu HAVING, que funciona para "filtrar" a partir de uma soma, que no caso voce fez dentro do Select ou seja não tem soma o seu select gera um numero puro, assim pode tentar trocar o HAVING por WHERE ou remover o Select após o HAVING e deixar apenas a sua SUM